# UILabel Subclass Text Disappear

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, subclass

I am trying to subclass UILabel.

Code .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface PercentLabel : UILabel
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat ratio;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *color1;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *color2;


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;

@end
```

Code .m

```
#import "PercentLabel.h"

@implementation PercentLabel

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [_color1 CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

}


@end
```

The custom properties work fine in Storyboard, but the Rectfill seems to cover the text that I have. If I set color with opacity 0.5 for example, then I am able to see the text behind the color.

Can someone explain why this is so and how to fix it so that text appear at top?

Comment: Whoops i found the solution already. Just need to put [super drawRect:rect]; after the drawing. Lulzz noob moment sry people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is put super at end of drawing code.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [_color1 CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
     [super drawRect:rect]; //<---

}
```

Super basically draws the default rendering of UILabel. So in this case, includes drawing of the text.